# how to compare two textbox.text is greater than other textbox.text with error provider?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, comparison, errorprovider

I put two textbox in user control in C# winform.`txtFrom` and `txtTo`. I want to compare two textbox.text and if `txtTo` is less than `txtFrom` , error provider are shown.
how do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't compare something **with** error provider. Error provider only shows that control has an error associated with control.

- Add [ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx) component to your form
- Compare `txtFrom.Text` and `txtTo.Text` (e.g. during Validating event)
- If text is less (I don't know what less means for you), then call `errorProvider1.SetError(txtTo, "Text is less than txtFrom")`, otherwise call `errorProvider1.SetError(txtTo, "")`

How to do comparison:

```
errorProvider1.SetError(txtFrom, "");
errorProvider1.SetError(txtTo, "");

int fromValue;
int toValue;

if (!Int32.TryParse(txtFrom.Text, out fromValue)
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(txtFrom, "Integer number required");
    return;
}

if (!Int32.TryParse(txtTo.Text, out toValue)
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(txtTo, "Integer number required");
    return;
}

if (toValue < fromValue)
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(txtTo, "To is less than From");
    return;
}
```

Consider also using `NumericUpDown` control to avoid text parsing stuff.

Comment: what is syntax of compare in C# winform?

Comment: @user1770370 comparison is not about WinForms, it's about C#. What kind of data you have in text boxes? Is it email addresses? What does 'less' mean then?

Comment: excuse me, yes you trust.type of input textbox is int

Comment: @user1770370 it's better to use `NumericUpDown` control for integer input. I'll add sample for textboxes

Comment: No, for range of input number

Comment: @Mr_Green I tend to use `Int32`, `Decimal`, `String` etc when dealing with static methods, and `int`, `decimal`, `string` when defining variables (MS often goes same way)